# Web scraping under div tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape a web site in which details are present in various div tags i have tried but somehow i am not able to scrape as every element is present inside div tag and further under div there are span tag too i have written the code it return empty string

here is mine code

```
    unspsc_link = "https://order.besse.com/Orders/Search/ProductSearch?query=34431"    
    link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
    
    prdItemNumbers = []
    prdTitles = []
    prdSubTitles = []
    prdNDCs = []
    prdUOM = []
    prdForm = []
    
    
    for row in soup.select('.row'):
        prdItemNumbers = row.select_one('.font-xs bg-teal')
        if prdItemNumbers is None:
            prdItemNumbers.append('N/A')
        else:
            prdItemNumbers.append(prdItemNumbers.text.strip().replace('\u200b',''))
    
        prdTitles = row.select_one('.header1')
        if prdTitles is None:
            prdTitles.append('N/A')
        else:
            prdTitles.append(prdTitles.text.strip())
    
        prdSubTitles = row.select_one('.header2')
        if prdSubTitles is None:
            prdSubTitles.append('N/A')
        else:
            prdSubTitles.append(prdSubTitles.text.strip())    
    
        prdNDCs = row.select_one('.col-sm-5')
        if prdNDCs is None:
            prdNDCs.append('N/A')
        else:
            prdNDCs.append(prdNDCs.text.strip())
    
        prdUOM = row.select_one('.col-sm-3')
        if prdUOM is None:
            prdUOM.append('N/A')
        else:
            prdUOM.append(prdUOM.text.strip())
    
        prdForm = row.select_one('.col-sm-4')
        if prdForm is None:
            prdForm.append('N/A')
        else:
            prdForm.append(prdForm.text.strip())
```

It throws error

```
    prdItemNumbers.append('N/A')

   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
for row in soup.select('.row'):
    prdItemNumbers = row.select_one('.font-xs bg-teal')
    if prdItemNumbers is None:
        prdItemNumbers.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdItemNumbers.append(prdItemNumbers.text.strip().replace('\u200b',''))
```

should be

```
for row in soup.select('.list-group-item'):
    prdItemNumber = row.select_one('.font-xs bg-teal')
    if prdItemNumber is None:
        prdItemNumbers.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdItemNumbers.append(prdItemNumber.text.strip().replace('\u200b',''))
```

The test should be on the `prdItemNumber` which is the current attempt to set an element as opposed to the list to append to. Same principle for the others; and you want to make all list variable names plural. Furthermore, the parent class to loop over should be `list-group-item`.

Content also appears to be dynamically loaded from XHR POST request. You could use selenium to load page and continue as before with page_source

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\HarrisQ\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://order.besse.com/Orders/Search/ProductSearch?query=34431')
WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-group-item")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source, 'lxml')
prdItemNumbers = []
prdTitles = []
prdSubTitles = []
prdNDCs = []
prdUOMs = []
prdForms = []

for row in soup.select('.list-group-item'):

    prdItemNumber = row.select_one('.font-xs bg-teal')
    if prdItemNumber is None:
        prdItemNumbers.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdItemNumbers.append(prdItemNumber.text.strip().replace('\u200b',''))

    prdTitle = row.select_one('.header1')
    if prdTitle is None:
        prdTitles.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdTitles.append(prdTitle.text.strip())

    prdSubTitle = row.select_one('.header2')
    if prdSubTitle is None:
        prdSubTitles.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdSubTitles.append(prdSubTitle.text.strip())    

    prdNDC = row.select_one('.col-sm-5')
    if prdNDC is None:
        prdNDCs.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdNDCs.append(prdNDC.text.strip())

    prdUOM = row.select_one('.col-sm-3')
    if prdUOM is None:
        prdUOMs.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdUOMs.append(prdUOM.text.strip())

    prdForm = row.select_one('.col-sm-4')
    if prdForm is None:
        prdForms.append('N/A')
    else:
        prdForms.append(prdForm.text.strip())
d.quit()
```

Comment: hey @QHarr what is the difference between the two?

Comment: prdItemNumbers  list to append to versus prdItemNumber the element you attempted to match on can be Tag or None in this case.

Comment: hey QHarr it retrieve only N/A and useless values i think i have not used the correct class this time it dont  throws error

Comment: Hi, quite possibly. I was fixing for your errors as shown.

Comment: This page also seems to rely on javascript to some extent.

Comment: hey @QHarr is there any way to scrap it and thanks for the help

Comment: I tried this it does retrieve but not in correct way as there are only five product but it gives the output for than 20 and maximum N/A . In prdItemNumbers it store N/A value. What is need to use selenium over here? I think some changes need to be made in beautiful section

Comment: I will have a look later. I was fixing for your reported error but should have checked the existing selectors.

Comment: Updated for you. Please see.